# Is there any way to remove "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' dependency from top level project gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

For firebase setup now my project gradle has  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`.

app gradle contains `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

I want to move firebase related code to the dynamic module

So I moved  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from `app Gradle` to `module Gradle`

but `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` is still related to full project.
 Is there any way to remove this dependency from top-level project Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `buildscript` block inside the `module/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //...
    }
    dependencies {
        //..
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```